# Neglect specific pattern from word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have word (each word) starting from : (colon) followed by digits and followed by anything

> Example1:
>   
> word --> :129]]  
>   
> output --> ]
>
> Example2:
>   
> word --> :20]sometext]  
>   
> output --> sometext]

- here :(d+)] is a fixed pattern in each word after that anything would remain in word.
- i want simply negate that pattern from word, what is a regular expression for that?
- and how can i remove last occurrence of open brace like i have <[ (or sometext123[) than result should be < (or sometext123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`\K` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) which discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. \K keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

```
:\d+]\K.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/60)

```
$re = "~:\d+]\K.*~m";
$str = ":20]sometext]";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: and how can i remove last occurrence of open brace like i have <[ (or sometext123[) than result should be < (or sometext123)

Comment: `\[(?=[^\[]*$)` matches the last `[` bracket. Replace the matched character with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use** `preg_replace`

```
$a=':20]sometext]';
$a=preg_replace("/:\d+\]/","",$a);
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want simply negate that pattern from word, what is a regular expression for that?

I suppose you want to remove it when you say negate. So use `/:\d+\]/g` and replace with an empty string.